# How to write a keyboard layout dll using the KbdLayerDescriptor symbol?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Looking an [example source code](http://pastebin.com/rRg54Www) wasn't enough, and I couldn't find any [official](http://levicki.net/articles/2006/09/29/HOWTO_Build_keyboard_layouts_for_Windows_x64.php) documentation about the`KbdLayerDescriptor`symbol. So I have still some questions about it :

- What is the purpose of the ligature table, or more precisely how does it works. Is it for writing pre‑composed characters ? If not, does it means automatically insert the ZERO WIDTH JOINER character, or it simply write several characters without ligature ?
- Is is possible to define three or more shift states with keys of the numeric pad ?
- I saw the`KBD_TYPE`need to be defined. What are the purpose of each integer values ?
- Is it possible to use Unicode values larger than 16 bits like the mathematical ?
- I saw keyboards layout use`[HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\DosKeybCodes]`and`[HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts]`but it seems it is not the only registry keys that need to be completed in order to register a system wide keyboard. So what are the required registry keys for installing a system wide keyboard layout ?

Comment: ***Note:*** this question isn't **TOO BROAD** as I'm narrowing the scope by asking specific questions on it.